# How to change link

Tags: html

I have a link of a hotel which shows us three types of rooms, I need to change that link somehow so it will become direct link to "modern" type room like if I clicked on that rooms, the thing is that that link doesn`t change after I choose "modern" rooms. Can someone please show me and explain how to do that? Here is the [link](http://www.taescherhof.ch/index.php/online-buchen/40-online-buchen#!/skd-ds/skd-offers?skd-checkin=%7BFN_CI_YYYY%7D-%7BFN_CI_MM%7D-%7BFN_CI_DD%7D&skd-checkout=%7BFN_CO_YYYY%7D-%7BFN_CO_MM%7D-%7BFN_CO_DD%7D&skd-channel-id=ibe&skd-price-type=asInPricelist&skd-time-price-base=stay%23%21%2Fskd-ds%2Fskd-offers)

Answer (score 0):

Post some code so we can see what you're dealing with...

Maybe try using an anchor to wrap the content:

```
<div id ="#anchor_here"> code here </div>
```

To link straight to that section:

```
<a href="#anchor_here"> go to section </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

if i correctly understand u, you wanna change your static link based on the end users choice, for this purpose you have several choice and the best one is using JavaScript and Jquery same as below:

in html:

```
<a id="linkId" href="your_linl"> select me </a>
```

in js:

```
$('#linkId').attr('href' , 'new link')
```

is it the answere you looking for ? if not, plz explain more .